# How can I change the value of a variable between functions in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a gome of tik-tak-toe. When one box is clicked, I want the value of var XorO to be X. I then want the value of XorO to be O for the next box that is clicked, and so on. Below, I will include some code that should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>tik-tak-toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tik-tak-toe.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tik-tak-toe.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="squares">
        <p id="topLeft" class="square" onclick="topLeft()"></p>
        <p id="topCenter" class="square" onclick="topCenter()"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var topLeftClicked=false;
var topCenterClicked=false;
var XorO="X";
function topLeft(){
    if(!topLeftClicked){
        topLeftClicked=true;
        document.getElementById("topLeft").innerHTML=
        XorO;
        if(XorO=="X"){
            XorO="O";
        }
        if(XorO=="O"){
            XorO="X";
        }
        return XorO;
    }
}
function topCenter(){
    if(!topCenterClicked){
        topCenterClicked=true;
        document.getElementById("topCenter").innerHTML=
        XorO;
        if(XorO=="X"){
            XorO="O";
        }
        if(XorO=="O"){
            XorO="X";
        }
        return XorO;/*this last section of code with the if statements is meant to change the value of XorO between "X" and "O" every time a function is carried out, but needless to say it doesnt work*/
    }
}
```

This is not the code for my entire tik tak toe game, as i a not finished. This should be enough togive you the jist of how my inexperienced coding brain thinks this should work. The thing I'm struggling with is changing the veriable XorY between "X" and "Y" ever time a box is pressed (Im trying to code a tik-tak-toe game).I tried making this it's own function, and as you see here i've tried doing it inside the function that is being carried out, but neither of them is able to make it so a different function recognizes the value of XorO as what i want it to. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have used two `if` conditions which change the value twice in each function. The code should be changed to `if`-`else`.

**Look at the explanation below:**

```js
if (XorO == "X") {
  XorO = "O";
}

// At this point the value will be 'O' and hence it will enter the next `if`
// condition and it will revert back to 'X'

if (XorO == "O") {
  XorO = "X";
}
```

You can also move your code to toggle the `X` or `O` values to a separate function so that it can be reused. Additionally, please stop using `var` for declaring variables, use `const` or `let` as per the new `ES6` standards.

###### Hence your code should look like below:

```js
let topLeftClicked = false;
let topCenterClicked = false;
let XorO = "X";

function topLeft() {
  if (!topLeftClicked) {
    topLeftClicked = !topLeftClicked;
    document.getElementById("topLeft").innerHTML = XorO;
    toggleXO();
  }
}

function topCenter() {
  if (!topCenterClicked) {
    topCenterClicked = true;
    document.getElementById("topCenter").innerHTML = XorO;
    toggleXO()
  }
}

function toggleXO() {
  if (XorO == "X") XorO = "O";
  else XorO = "X";
}
```

```html
<div id="squares">
  <p id="topLeft" class="square" onclick="topLeft()">TopLeft</p>
  <p id="topCenter" class="square" onclick="topCenter()">TopCenter</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The "stop using var advice is very much appreciated. the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Use else if to make two decisions**

```
 if (XorO == "X") {
  XorO = "O";
} else if (XorO == "O") {
  XorO = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since XorO is a global variable you should not need to return anything from the functions.  But your logic doesn't make sense to me.  I put together a small sample to show another way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>tik-tak-toe</title>
 <style>
  table
  {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  table td
  {
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
  window.document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td').forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
  var XorO = "X";

  function clickHandler()
  {
   // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
   this.innerHTML = XorO;
   XorO = (XorO == "X" ? "O" : "X");
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

For this sample I used a basic 3x3 table.  Now I need to assign a click event handler to each of the table td cells.  There are 2 ways you can do this. 1) Use javascript to assign the event handler.  2) Use the onclick attribute of the td cell.  My script tag starts after the table has been defined otherwise the javascript would fail because the table isn't there yet.

1. window.document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td') will return an array of all the table td cells.
   .forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", clickHandler)) will loop the array and assign the function 'clickHandler' to each td click event.
2. td onclick="clickHandler();" is the 2nd way to assign a event handler to each td cell.

The clickHandler function places the value of XorO in the clicked td cell and the next line sets the new value of XorO.  I used a ternary statement for this, a short version of if/else.

You can also give each td cell a id so your clickHandler will know which td cell was clicked.  Then you can use those id's in the win, lose or draw formulas.

Comment: Hey man I'm sure this is a better way to do it. It is too complicated for me though. I dont really know what jquery is at all, and I dont recognize a bunch of the commands you used. Thanks for trying to help, but it just went way over my head.

Comment: @tv_dinner: My code doesn't use jQuery at all.  I can explain in more detail if you want.  I mainly wanted to show you that you don't need 9 functions when all you really need is 1.

Comment: I am interested in learning how that works. I dont recognize most of the key words, so i get lost quickly in trying to read it.

Comment: @tv_dinner: See my edit above.  If you have more questions just ask.